# The ArrayFlatten seems to have no effect for some reason

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am a new Mathematica user, I am attempting to use *ArrayFlatten* but it seems not to work in this case. My codes are below,

```
w = IntegerPartitions[10, {3}]
x = Permutations[{a, b, c}, {3}]
simlength = Length[x]
simp = Transpose@w[[1 ;;]] x[[#]] & /@ Range[1, simlength, 1]
simp//MatrixForm
```

then I use

```
ArrayFlatten[...Outputfromprevioushere...]//MatrixForm
```

*ArrayFlatten* seems to have no effect at all. Is there anything I might be missing? Thanks a lot

Comment: [MatrixForm >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html): _MatrixForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation._

Comment: does `Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{simp}]] // MatrixForm` give the desired output?

Comment: Thanks so much! This solves the problem. All is ok now

Comment: Rob, Welcome to mma.se. We suggest 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs!](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: Will do! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{simp}]] // MatrixForm
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]